# Bash script check if user-input matches certain form

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, if-statement

Below you can see my bash script

```
#createSession.sh

echo "Welcome to ADS2 Session Start..."

while [ true ]
do
echo "Starting service Daemon on the targert"
echo "Enter the ip-address of the target"
read x
if [ -z "$x" ]
then 
    echo "ip-address is empty"
else
    echo "Connecting with target..."
    if [[ $x =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]
    then
        ssh nvidia@"$x" "/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin/ads2 svcd&"
        echo "connection succeded"
        break
    else
        "Make sure the io address in the coorect form"  
    fi

fi
done
```

**First question**

As you see, the script checks if the user input machtes the ip-address form. However, i would like the script to also accept the ip address as a string which has this form `fdt-c-agx-4arbitrary numbers`. The last part of the string can be any arbitrary 4 numbers. As a result, the if statement be like

`if [[ $x =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]] || [ $x = #machtes fdt-c-agx-4arbitrary digits]`

**Second question**

The ip address could be entered in the right form, however does not exist. Consequently, the ssh returns in this case `ssh connection time out`. However the string `connection succeded` will be printed which is not true. So how can i make the scripts enough clever to realize that the connection in this case is not established?

Thnaks in advance

Comment: `As a result, the if statement be like` Soo... write it that way? You have `^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$` as an example, so just write the same that matches the other one.

Comment: So what do you think `[0-9]` means? I recommend regex crosswords, available on the net, to learn regex in no time.

Comment: @KamilCuk your write. numbers between 0 and 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can i make the scripts enough clever to realize that the connection in this case is not established?

Just check the `ssh` exit status.

```
if ! ssh something@something something ; then
     echo "Och nuuu - problem with ssh" >&2
     exit 1
else
     echo "Yes! It worked! Good job!"
fi
```

> As a result, the if statement be like

Sure:

```
if 
   [[ $x =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]] ||
   [[ $x =~ ^fdt-c-agx-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$ ]]
then
   ...
```

> ```
> while [ true ]
> ```

Just:

```
while true
```

The `[` command checks if the string `true` has nonzero length. Because it has, it's a success. You could write `[ anything ]` with same result. But just `true`, it's a command on it's own.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. However, the OR operator seems not to work. I tried every condition independently and it works. However, its more efficient with or. Am I using the or operator wrongly?

Comment: And for listening to the ssh, when the ip address is right, it asks again for the password like if its calling the connection again

Comment: I solved the problem with OR operator. However the if statement regarding listening to ssh exit status prompts the user to enter the password again

Comment: `if statement regarding listening to ssh exit status prompts the user to enter the password again` so? That's good - you should authenticate yourself before connecting  to remote server. If you do not want to give password, research public key authentication ie. `ssh-copy-id`. If you want your credentials to be cached, research ssh-agent and maybe `ControlMaster` option to ssh.

Comment: that's right. However it already asks after checking the ip address and executes the command remotely. Why would it ask again when i observe the ssh exit ?.